# Blazor Catch-all route exceptions

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I have ASP.NET 5.0 Blazor Server-Side Application, which serves content based on the route.
The only exceptions from this pattern are the login/user settings.

My first approach was, to use the [catch-all route parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#catch-all-route-parameters).

```
@page "/{*pageRoute}"
```

This would work fine, but now the pages for login, etc. are no longer available because the catch-all, catches them as well.

Is it possible to implement it like "catch-all, except these"?

Comment: Is this not what `<NotFound>` does in app.razor? Or more specifically the renderfragment called `NotFound` in the `Router` component.

Comment: @BrianParker This seems technically correct. But looks a bit "hacked". Currently I am trying out to work with a "prefix folder" `@page "Prefix/{*pageRoute}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement it like "catch-all, except these"?

No.

For your need, use [Route parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-parameters) or you can check your parameters in case **catch all** then check in condition control structure(s).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now fixed in the latest version of Blazor.  A catchall parameter works as follows:

If a route matches an existing route, that route is used.  If it does not match any other existing route, then the catchall route is used.  It's the "route of last resort."

```
@page "/catch-all/{*pageRoute}"

<PageTitle>Catch All</PageTitle>

<h1>Catch All Parameters Example</h1>

 <p>Add some URI segments to the route and request the page again. 
</p>

 <p>
  PageRoute: @PageRoute
 </p>

 @code {
     [Parameter]
     public string? PageRoute { get; set; }
 }
```

Now run your app. All pages such as "/counter" works as intended.  If a route is not found, then the catchall page is used.

Comment: Getting this error when trying to wire up what you're saying here. "Object of type 'PublicWebsiteBlazorServer.Pages.Catchall' does not have a property matching the name 'catchall'."

Comment: You need to add a Property to the Page to accept the string that is passed to it.  I expanded the code sample to make this more clear.