# .net 8 Blazor Catch-all routes does not style sheets and static files

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I have a requirement to catch app the routes after "/" and then lookup into the routes table in the database, once the path is found then load the relevant page in .net 8 Blazor server side app.

I have had a look at [Catch-all route parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#catch-all-route-parameters) documentation and also a related question on Stack overflow [Blazor Catch-all route exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759884/blazor-catch-all-route-exceptions) but all these does not solve my requirements which was much easier to do in .net mvc.

```
@page "/{**pageRoute}"
```

When I use the above technique it does navigate but it does not load any stylesheet and static file like images in the page. If I use "NavigationManager.NavigateTo" then it loads the home page on stylesheets urls and static file.

Also in Router in .net Blazor 8 does not load NotFound RenderFregement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify `@page "/{**pageRoute}"`to `@page "/{*pageRoute:nonfile}"`

I once faced the same issue and asked for help on github,you could check the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/50471)

For NotFound section,you may check thie part of the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#provide-custom-content-when-content-isnt-found):

> This section only applies to Blazor WebAssembly apps. Blazor Web Apps
> don't use the NotFound template (...), but the
> template is supported for backward compatibility to avoid a breaking
> change in the framework. Blazor Web Apps typically process bad URL
> requests by either displaying the browser's built-in 404 UI or
> returning a custom 404 page from the ASP.NET Core server via ASP.NET
> Core middleware (for example, UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects / API
> documentation).

Comment: Great, Thanks @Ruikai Feng, I saw this option from Github Copilot but that was asking me to do in the program.cs file in the fallback configurations. Yes, solve the issue that I was facing.