# .NET 8 Blazor - Stopped Accessing wwwroot Folder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, wwwroot

I have been working on a project in .NET 8, using the Blazor Web App template with Server rendering. Up until now, my project has been working flawlessly. However, after launching my project today, I cannot access anything in my wwwroot folder. Nothing changed between when it worked perfectly last night and this morning.

- The wwwroot folder is still in the same default location, directly in my project folder.
- I can no longer display any images in my componenets; I just get the alt text instead.
- None of my bootstrap or custom css stylesheet files can be accessed. The App.razor  section has not been modified whatsoever, and it is still located in its default location under the project/Components folder. My project acts as if there is no  tag to these stylesheets.
- Other external  tags in my App.razor files work just fine (such as Google Font stylesheets or FontAwesome). Only the tags for files in my wwwroot folder are not working.
- My project is not giving me any errors. It simply just ignores items in my wwwroot folder.
- I have tried updating visual studio, and building/rebuilding my solution.

How can I further troubleshoot this issue and restore access to items in my wwwroot folder? I have other .NET 8 Blazor projects with the exact same setup that are still functioning correctly. I am not sure where this issue came from. Thank you for any insight.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser?

Comment: I did notice a difference between working projects and this one. The response header for these resources is different. For the project resources that won't load, response header lists "Blazor-Enhanced-Nav: allow", "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store", and "Pragma: no-cache". The working projects do not list these in the response header. Additionally, the actual working response for bootstrap.min.css is the bootstrap file. For my broken project, the actual response is the App.razor file.

Comment: Have you checked if the route of your razor component matches static files like this issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77526733/net-8-blazor-catch-all-routes-does-not-style-sheets-and-static-files/77527142#77527142

Comment: can you hit the files in wwroot manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was I had a page url with only variables. For example, I had `@page "/{Var1}/{Var2}"` as one of the page url options. Although this worked at first, upon restarting my laptop, I began having this issue until the line was removed.